# Resizeable textarea when replying to employers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

As highlighted in the image below, the textarea when responding to messages from employers is, in my opinion, too small and not resizeable. It can then become quite tedious scrolling through the text, especially when looking for errors.

[image]

**Can we have the textarea resize-able?**

---

Personally, I like to read through what I've written without having to scroll though it so, as a workaround, I am manually editing the css.

For those not in the know, here is what to do on Chrome:

- Right-Click on the textarea and select *Inspect*
- On the right, in the *Styles* tab, where it says `.msg-form textarea` add the style `resize: vertical;`

Comment: While it couldn't hurt to make the field larger and/or resizable, the obvious solution seems to be composing prose in a *proper* editor and then just pasting it in.