# Increase the height of textarea

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design, user-experience

When I click the **[Easy apply](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)** button, I will redirect to this kind of page and request to fill in the application form. However, the textarea size for the **Introduce yourself** section only has `3` visible rows.

```
<textarea rows="3"></textarea>
```

---

[image]

Is it possible to increase the height of textarea or could be resizable? I just want to make comfortable for reading and writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report and sorry for the delay to address this.

Today we shipped an update to the application form that increases the height of the textarea and also makes it vertically resizable.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That looks good to me.

Answer (score 10):

Yes please. It's been like this forever and I'm amazed it isn't fixed yet.

See also [Resizeable textarea when replying to employers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351451/49942)

I get that Jobs isn't the biggest revenue stream but come on.

I note that it is *not* even resizeable, either -- the CSS specifies `resize: none`! Is that [evidence of malice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) or what, i.e. is SE trying to make that feature unusable, hoping that developers won't use that "Optional" feature?

See also [How do I disable the resizable property of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-do-i-disable-the-resizable-property-of-a-textarea#comment106087825_5235142)

> For the love of all that is good, please don't do this on an actual textarea or you will alienate your power users. Breaking core browser functionality should be considered a nuclear option.

---

It might be nice of you to display a preview too -- "here's what your text looks like, a chance to reread it before we send it" -- like you do for any other post on Stack Exchange. And indicate whether the text area supports markdown. But at least make the thing tall enough to read.

But just this change, to height defined by the the markup, would be a good start.

A workaround of course is to compose your text externally (e.g. in Notepad) and then copy-and-paste into the text area, even so that UI remains annoyingly inept.